# Ubuntu can't run on vm-ware after installing local packages

Tags: ubuntu, reboot, cross-compilation, petalinux

i want to do petalinux cross-compilation at ubuntu on vm-ware and offline.
so, i downloaded all needed packages and installed them.
and then i tried to restart ubuntu. but, unfortunately, ubuntu not run.
vm-ware version is 15.x, ubuntu version is 16.04

here, my errors :
[image]

help me, please. sorry my mistake.

this is my install packages list without their dependencies.

```
iproute2 gcc g++ net-tools libncurses5-dev zlib1g:i386 libssl-dev flex bison libselinux1 xterm autoconf libtool texinfo zlib1g-dev gcc-multilib build-essential screen pax gawk python3 python3-pexpect python3-pip python3-git python3-jinja2 xz-utils debianutils iputils-ping libegl1-mesa libsdl1.2-dev pylint3 cpio chrpath socat tftp tftpd
```

**Sorry,dear everyone.
For this question, i tried and fixed the errors.
so, i tried to install one-by-one. And the problem is libdbus-..--.deb package. if it had been installed, system breaked.
What is libdbus package's function? and why we use it? if not install, what problem ? if install, why this problem happens?
Now, i have not installed it, but not any problem.
thanks .**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i tried to solve my problem. so i changed my question a bit.